# SSIS fast load data flow task equivalent using only T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have an `SSIS package` that loads one table into another on the same server (but across databases). Eg:

```
> OLE DB Source [Server1].[DatabaseA].[dbo].[Table1]<br>
> OLE DB Destination: [Server1].[DatabaseB].[dbo].[Table1]
```

(The tables have identical definitions). My company wants to move away from using `SSIS` and do all operations in `T-SQL` if possible. I can use `T-SQL` to insert the rows, of course:

```
Use [Server1]
INSERT INTO [DatabaseB].[dbo].[Table1]
SELECT * FROM [DatabaseA].[dbo].[Table1]
```

...but for very large tables it is very slow. I'd like to be able to buffer the data using the options available via `SSIS`, like `DefaultBufferMaxRows` and `DefaultBufferSize`. But I can't see how those options are available to me when loading the data via `SSIS`. I've set the `TABLOCK` query hint to improve performance but I'm most interested in the buffer settings. Is there a way to access those with `T-SQL`?

Comment: [Use BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET(BULK...) to import data to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks Larnu, I know that I can bulk insert from a file but I don’t know how to access the bulk insert options when transferring from table to table.

Comment: `OPENROWSET` doesn't need to refer to a file, @mezzanayne .[Using OPENROWSET with SELECT and the SQL Server Native Client OLE DB Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-openrowset-with-select-and-the-sql-server-native-client-ole-db-provider)

Comment: Thank you for the additional comment, Larnu. I can use `INSERT` with `SELECT...FROM..OPENROWSET`, no problem. But I'm still not clear on how to access the `BULK` load options using this setup. Can you please provide syntax? The code examples that I've found that use `BULK` are importing from a file, which is not my situation.

Comment: To be clear @Larnu, [this MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) specifies that `BULK INSERT` "Imports _a data file_ into a database table or view in a user-specified format in SQL Server". Yet I can transfer the data via SSIS data flow task and still have access to the `BULK INSERT` options even though the data aren't being imported from file. I want to know why this is. Any continued help is appreciated.

Comment: @mezzanayne did you solve this? I have a very similar question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid not, @Gakku. We ended up just sticking with the SSIS solution.